# How to style the WFS layer in openscales?

Tags: geoserver, flex, openscales

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Styling the WFS point layer (openscales 1.1 & Flex 3)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22745/styling-the-wfs-point-layer-openscales-1-1-flex-3)

I am very new to openscales...
I want to change the styles of the WFS point layer dynamically by giving rules. I want to show some jpeg/image as the point in the openscales.

Any idea how to define the rules to change the styles of default point style.

Comment: I am very new to openscales... I want to change the styles of the WFS point layer dynamically by giving rules. I want to show some jpeg/iamge as the point in the openscales.

any idea how to define the rules to change the styles of default point style.

thanks in advance..